# Layer to KML design

Tags: kml, layer-to-kml

I would like to understand the logic behind layer to KML. I want to know how to ensure the field I want goes in the dark blue banner. It seems kind of random to me. It is not always the first column and it doesn't matter if one of your columns name is "Name". I played around for a bit creating multiple variations of the same layer and turning them into KMLs.

[image]

Comment: Documentation https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using ArcGIS Desktop from the screenshot and the tool name. As far as I know, the title of the popup is controlled from **Display** tab of the [Layer properties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/setting-layer-properties.htm). By default it is the first string field in your table. The style of the table is controlled by the **HTML Popup** tab of the Layer Properties again. In your snip, this is the default HTML popup in ArcMap and if you use other XSL templates, you will see the change in your KML. Also refer to

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/kml/creating-kml-in-arcgis-for-desktop.htm#GUID-CC20DE78-B023-4EC1-B6B8-8F2B1E4A5E51 and

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/setting-html-pop-up-properties-for-feature-layers.htm